# Stored Procedure or calculations via IQueryable?

Tags: c#, database, design-patterns, architecture

This is a question that is based on choosing performance over design practices. If I have a method that will be executed many times a second;

```
public static IQueryable<IPerson> InRadius(this IQueryable<IPerson> query, Coordinate center, double radius)
{
    return (from u in query
            where CallHeavyMathFormula(u, center, radius)
            select u);
}
```

This extension method for IQueryable generates a SQL that does some heavy maths calculation (Cosine, Sine, etc). This would mean the application sends 1-2KB of sql to the server per call.

I've heard of placing all application logic, in your application. I also would like to change to a database such as azure or one of those scalable databases in the future. How do I handle something like this? Should I leave it as it is now or write stored procedures? How do applications like twitter or facebook do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stored procedure languages tend to tie you tightly to a particular vendor or product.  Consider the possibility of having to rewrite if you anticipate migrating in the future.

With that said, I think such a decision depends on other factors, like whether or not it requires moving a lot of data out of a database and into memory.  How much data; how much memory; how many bytes on the wire back and forth?  These are the things you'll have to send.

1-2KB per database call doesn't sound like a lot to me.

I wouldn't consider calculating sines and cosines heavy math.  A dynamic FFT or linear algebra solution would be far more challenging.  Nothing that I'd call heavy would execute several times a second.

It sounds to me like you'd be safe with keeping this calculation on the application side.

Answer (score 1):

First, depending on the used db, it might cache execution plans and results for both stored procedures and ad-hoc queries. This should be the main reason to go for in code vs stored procedure. You might also be able to us a .net function inside sql, to keep part of the condition as .net code (too hard to write condition as sql, etc)
Then instead of hitting db too often, i would try to cache results.

It is not a 'sin' to have in a application both stored procedures (mainly for complex queries, where SP would create a great improvement) and ad-hoc code through iqueriable.

Using the sql profiler could also help you decide on the best solution.

And as long as you don't have the migration to another db on the near future plan or if it is just a 'might happen', ignore it for now, consider doing it later as part of the necessary refactoring at that moment.